# ProgrammingError after setting up postgres db

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am getting this error trying to save an instance in the admin page,
every time I hit the save button, I get this error, also some views are returning the same error

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/report_testing/reporttested/add/

Django Version: 1.10.4
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'report_testing',
 'bootstrap3']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  544.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  211.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1509.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view



149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in inner
  185.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1449.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_model
  1007.         obj.save()
File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  796.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base



824.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  908.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  947.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1045.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1054.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

    File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
      79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

    File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
      64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql

, params)

    File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
      94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

    File "/home/fatah/PycharmProjects/API_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
      64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

    Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/report_testing/reporttested/add/
    Exception Value: column "test_user_id" of relation "report_testing_reporttested" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._testing_reporttested" ("title", "tested", "pdf", "test_user...
                                                             ^
```

I have tried

```
(env) M51AC ~/PycharmProjects/API_test $ ./manage.py makemigrations report_testing
No changes detected in app 'report_testing'
(env) M51AC ~/PycharmProjects/API_test $ ./manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, report_testing, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
(env) M51AC ~/PycharmProjects/API_test $ ./manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: bootstrap3, messages, staticfiles
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, report_testing, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

./manage.py showmigrations

```
admin


[X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
report_testing
 [X] 0001_initial
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

model.py

```
class ReportTested(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, unique=True)
      tested = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
      pdf = models.FilePathField(path= settings.PDF_DIRECTORY, blank=True)
      test_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='reportstested', null=True, blank=True)
```

0001_initial.py

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
      initial = True
      dependencies = [
          migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL), 
]
      operation = [
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=500, unique=True)),
                ('tested', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('pdf', models.FilePathField(blank=True, path=b'/home/PycharmProjects/API_test/report_testing/static/media/pdfs')),
                ('test_user', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='reportstested', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL))   

      options={
                'verbose_name_plural': 'PDFS Tested',
            },
        ),
],
```

Everything was working fine using sqlite before setting up postgres db. 
Am I doing something wrong and how can I fix it ?

Comment: I am sorry It's all fixed now :)

Comment: The error shows that `test_user_id` column is missing from the database for your `ReportTested` model, but it's not clear why. Please show the model and its migrations, and the output of `./manage.py showmigrations`.

Comment: Is it because of the ForeignKey  of test_user ?

Comment: Yes, it's the column for `ReportTested.test_user` foreign key that is missing. Please show the `0001_initial` migration for the `report_testing` app.

Comment: Please take a look at `0001_initial.py`

Comment: The migration includes the field, so the column should have been created when you ran the migration. If you don't have any important data in the database, the easiest approach would be to drop the database and run migrate again.